# Play two sounds at the same time in mathematica. For example the inventions of Bach NO.8

Tags: functions, sound, signal-processing

I use mathematica to play the Inventions No8 by Bach. I want to play the two parts (by right and left hands )at the same time. But I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
 - Clear["`*"]
{a, b, c, d} = 0.8*{1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125};

{c4, d4, e4, f4, g4, a4, b4} = {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11};
{c5, d5, e5, f5, g5, a5, b5} = {c4, d4, e4, f4, g4, a4, b4} + 12;
b\[Flat] = 10;

time1 = Join[ConstantArray[b, 7], ConstantArray[c, 10], 
   ConstantArray[b, 6]];
note1 = {None, f4, a4, f4, c5, f4, f5,
    e5, d5, c5, d5, c5, b4,
    a4, b4, a4, g4,
    f4, a4, c5, a4, f5, c5} /. {b4 -> b\[Flat]};


Sound@MapThread[SoundNote[#1, #2, "Piano"] &, {note1, time1}]
Sound@MapThread[
  SoundNote[#1, #2, "Piano"] &, {Join[
    ConstantArray[None, 4], (note1 - 12) /. {None - 12 -> None}], 
   Join[ConstantArray[b, 4], time1]}]
```

Comment: From the help  :"Sound[{SoundNote["C", {0, 0.3}], SoundNote["G", {0.1, 0.5}]}]" this plays 2 overlapping notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the two lines separately like this, you can use sampled audio to turn each `Sound` into a waveform.  Then you can simply add the two waveforms together to "mix" them.

```
rh = Sound@MapThread[SoundNote[#1, #2, "Piano"] &, {note1, time1}]
lh = Sound@MapThread[SoundNote[#1, #2, "Piano"] &, 
  {Join[ConstantArray[None, 4], (note1 - 12) /. {None - 12 -> None}], 
     Join[ConstantArray[b, 4], time1]}]

{rhaudio, lhaudio} = PadRight[First@*AudioData /@ {rh, lh}];
(* Note that the two clips are of different lengths;  
   PadRight pads the end of the shorter one with silence *)

Audio[rhaudio + lhaudio]
```

This yields an audio clip with the left hand coming in one quarter note early.  I think the `4`s in the definition of the left-hand line should be `6`s instead (since this piece is in $\mathbf{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{3}{4}}$ time and there are 6 eight notes per bar.)